# Excell 2007 cell auto-complete too slow for worksheets with 10,000 to 15,000 rows

Tags: vsto, excel-2007

I'm doing a Excel 2007 VSTO template where I load a worksheet with between 10.000 to 15.000 rows of data,  and was counting on using the built-in excel cell auto-complete to speed future data entry. Nevertheless I noticed the auto-complete is very slow, it takes a couple of minutes for excel to, after starting to edit a cell, be able to finish the "internal scan" of all the upper cells in other to be able to find a match. Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Contacted MS support and they said it was by design and could only be solved by a change request to the product team which would take a log time.